# How to replace a string in a string with a given array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I get a array which is like:

```
const u = ['JS', 'rock']
```

And I get a string which is like:

```
const s = 'I like JS, and rock'
```

Here is my work:

```
u.map(e => s.replaceAll(e,'hi'))
```

And here is the expected result:

```
I like hi, and hi
```

But here is the result I get:

```
I like JS, and rock
```

How can I correct it?

Comment: Your code works too, you forgot to re-assign the output of `s.replaceAll(...)` back to `s`. `replaceAll` does not replace the string in place, but rather gets you a new one.

Comment: @Akxe I'm finding it returns an array of two strings, neither of them being what the poster wanted.

Comment: @Noah The map function does, but the `replaceAll` function on its own, does only return modified string...

Answer (score 2):

```
 const s = 'I like JS, and rock'
 const u = ['JS', 'rock']

 console.log(u.reduce((a, c) => a.replaceAll(c,'hi'), s));
```

you can use reduce instead of map

Answer (score 0):

If you join your search terms with a pipe (`|`), you can actually do this with one regular expression (generally faster than mapping in JS). You can pass `'g'` as the second argument to the `RegExp` constructor to make sure it's a global search on the string.

```js
const u = ['JS', 'rock']

const s = 'I like JS, and rock'

const regex = new RegExp(u.join('|'), 'g');

console.log(
  s.replace(regex, 'hi')
)
```

Comment: No problem! If you have a choice between this and the other solution posted, I'd recommend this one since it is a good amount faster on average.

Answer (score 0):

s.replaceAll returning a value but not edit s .
so you can use this code:

```
let s = 'I like JS, and rock'
const u = ['JS', 'rock']
u.map(e =>{ s=s.replaceAll(e,'hi')})
```